# Identifying Local Maximas using For & If Statements in R

Tags: r

I am trying to build a for loop with a nested if statement to check for the maximum values in a vector. I hope to take this code and apply it to spectrum data.

Right now it's returning an error that I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Do I need to break up my logical operators in my If statement?

Code:

```
r <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Peaks <- c()
indPeaks <- c()
length(r)
for(x in length(r)) {
 if((r[x-1]<r[x] & r[x+1]<r[x])==TRUE){
    Peaks <-r[x]
    indPeaks <- which(r == r[x])
  }
}
```

> Error in if ((r[x - 1] < r[x] & r[x + 1] < r[x]) == TRUE) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Please see [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please do not post pictures of code and data. They should be included as text in the question itself. This makes it much easier to copy/paste to test the code and makes it easier to search later.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment about posting your code directly. That enables us to copy your code into a console and run it.

Comment: You have two problems. First `x in length(r)` only refers to one value...the last position available in `r`. Second, `r[x-1]` will return NA if x is 1, and `r[x+1]` will return NA if x is length(x) because there is no data outside of your vector. The results of NA < r[x] is NA...and you need TRUE or FALSE as a result.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question and added the code. Just wanted to show the error I was getting.

Comment: If this is for an assignment then fixing those problems should help. Otherwise you might want to look up the functions `max()` and `which.max()` which will be faster than a loop.

Comment: @AdamSampson Those are for global max, not local. I guess I'd look at `diff` and `sign` to find local maxes in a vectorized way.

Comment: Also you don't need the `== TRUE` part because  `r[x-1]<r[x] & r[x+1]<r[x]` will evaluate to TRUE or FALSE and that will tell the if statement whether to proceed or not. Not a big deal just thought I would let you know